# Передача объекта между Tab

Tags: java, android

Имеется несколько Tab (TabLayout).

Необходимо передать экземпляр класса из одного Tab в другое при свайпе или выборе вкладки.

Проблема в том что я не знаю, как это во фрагменте сделать.
Там нету ни одного метода отвечающий за выбор вкладки или свайп.

Все действия прописаны в отдельном классе Pager. Экземпляр добавляется в 1 Tab, поэтому я не могу его в Pager передать.

SmartPager:

```
public class SmartphonePager extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    int tabCount;

    public SmartphonePager(FragmentManager fm, int tabCount) {
        super(fm);
        this.tabCount = tabCount;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                SmartphoneMainTab smartphoneMainTab = new SmartphoneMainTab();
                return smartphoneMainTab;
            case 1:
                SmartphoneDisplayTab smartphoneDisplayTab = new SmartphoneDisplayTab();
                return smartphoneDisplayTab;
            case 2:
                SmartphoneStructureTab smartphoneStructureTab = new SmartphoneStructureTab();
                return smartphoneStructureTab;
            case 3:
                SmartphoneHardwareTab smartphoneHardwareTab = new SmartphoneHardwareTab();
                return smartphoneHardwareTab;
            case 4:
                SmartphoneCameraTab smartphoneCameraTab = new SmartphoneCameraTab();
                return smartphoneCameraTab;
            case 5:
                SmartphoneDataTransferTab smartphoneDataTransferTab = new SmartphoneDataTransferTab();
                return smartphoneDataTransferTab;
            case 6:
                SmartphoneBatteryTab smartphoneBatteryTab = new SmartphoneBatteryTab();
                return smartphoneBatteryTab;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tabCount;
    }
}
```

SmartTab:

```
public class SmartphoneMainTab extends Fragment {
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_smartphone_main, container, false);
    }
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        progressBar = (ProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    }
```

В какой метод нужно закидывать (пример)

```
Fragment f = new EmployeeDetails();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("ID", "123");
            f.setArguments(bundle);
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, f);
            ft.commit();
```

И еще вопрос как объект передать? у Bundle нету команды вроде putObject()

Comment: фрагмент1 =(интерфейс)=> активность => фрагмент2. Второй фрагмент должен быть создан (и тогда через его функцию), если нет - то создавать через `newInstance`

Comment: а примера кода нету случайно?

Comment: или ссылки на ресурс

Comment: https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/176-urok-106-android-3-fragments-vzaimodejstvie-s-activity.html посмотрите тут

Comment: но ведь там по нажатию кнопки происходит передача строки в someEventListener, который инициализируется в onAttach, а я хочу чтобы при переключении Tab либо swipe. Я просто не знаю какие методы за это отвечают

Comment: `onAttach` срабатывает на прикреплении фрагмента к активности. Например, на `replace`, как у вас.